# In a maven multi-module project, how to access the spring beans from one module to another

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, spring-bean

I have a maven multi-module application as below

```
parent
-+ module 1
-+ module 2
-+ module 3
```

Module 2 and module 3 are seperate jars and added as depencency in module 1.

All the modules have application-context assigned to it.

I  need to get the spring beans from module 3 and module 2 to module 1.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case you are using spring with xml configuration files you should import module 2 and module 3 application-context files in the module 1 application-context like below :

```
<import resource="classpath*:file/location/module1application-context.xml" />
<import resource="classpath*:file/location/module2application-context.xml" />
```